# Entity with EmbeddedId fails retrieve from cache after deployment reload

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching, wildfly

I'm on WildFly 10, Hibernate 5.2.2 and a simple JAX-RS/JPA app with an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEmbeddableId id;

    // other fields, hashCode, equals, getters and setters

}

@Embeddable
public class MyEmbeddableId implements Serializable {

    private String foo;

    private String bar;

    // hashCode, equals, getters and setters

}
```

All works like expected, but if I reload the app (not restarting WildFly) then on entity load I get:

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String MyEmbeddableId.foo] by reflection for persistent property [MyEmbeddableId#foo] : MyEmbeddableId@33675787
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.TypeEquivalance.hashCode(TypeEquivalance.java:24)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.concurrent.jdk8backported.BoundedEquivalentConcurrentHashMapV8.get(BoundedEquivalentConcurrentHashMapV8.java:2427)
    at org.infinispan.container.DefaultDataContainer.get(DefaultDataContainer.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.container.EntryFactoryImpl.innerGetFromContainer(EntryFactoryImpl.java:288)
    at org.infinispan.container.EntryFactoryImpl.getFromContainer(EntryFactoryImpl.java:258)
    at org.infinispan.container.EntryFactoryImpl.wrapEntryForReading(EntryFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitDataReadCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistReadAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:345)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:330)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:411)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:403)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.get(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.access.InvalidationCacheAccessDelegate.get(InvalidationCacheAccessDelegate.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.ReadOnlyAccess.get(ReadOnlyAccess.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.CacheHelper.fromSharedCache(CacheHelper.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.getFromSharedCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1218)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1101)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1146)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1005)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2460)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2422)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field MyEmbeddableId.foo to MyEmbeddableId
```

If I restart WildFly, it works again. Also, if I disable caching all works fine also after deployment reload.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in Hibernate or WildFly?

Comment: I see that the exception is thrown by `Field.get(object)` "if the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field (or a subclass or implementor thereof)". Maybe Hibernate uses a proxy of some sort for cached entities?

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11080